# Formatting the output XML using Transformer

Tags: java, xml

Is it possible to format the output XML file from the Transformer object.

As of now, I got these as the output:

```
<A name="a" type="a">
     <B name="b" type="b" width="100" height="100" />
     <B name="b" type="b" width="100" height="200" />
     <B name="b" type="b" width="100" height="300" />
     <B name="b" type="b" width="100" height="400" />
</A>
```

But I want something that look like this:

```
<A name="a"
   type="a">
   <B name="b"
      type="b"
      width="100"
      height="100" />
   <B name="b"
      type="b"
      width="100"
      height="200" />
   <B name="b"
      type="b"
      width="100"
      height="300" />
   <B name="b"
      type="b"
      width="100"
      height="400" />
</A>
```

Here is my code snippet for the transformer:

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(file);
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would save xml in tmp file, then read from it line by line format it and save. Example for one line

```
    String line = "    <B name=\"b\" type=\"b\" width=\"100\" height=\"100\" />";
    String indent = line.startsWith("<A") ? "   " : "       "; 
    line = line.replaceAll("(type|width|height)", "\n" + indent +  "$1");
    System.out.println(line);
```

output

```
<B name="b" 
   type="b" 
   width="100" 
   height="100" />
```

Comment: are there other ways to do that?, I mean. It'll only work if the attributes I had is limited to type|width|height, right? but what if I have no idea what the attributes are beforehand? thanks btw.